# Spring Boot clone from Github does not work and added other files

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-boot, github

My friend and I wanted to work on a Spring Boot application together so we think working with Github would be the best solution. So I created a Maven Spring Boot in Eclipse, which looks like this:

[image: rep]

Afterwards, I created a Github repository and pushed the project on it. Which looks like this:
[image: github]

But when my friend clone this repository into his Eclipse, the whole repository does not work and it looks like this:
[image: friend]

We searched for a solution but nothing works. Do you know the answer how we could fix that so that he have the same files like on the first screenshot? We would be very happy :)

Comment: Every one of those X badges says what the error is.

Comment: check if you you have Spring framework installed on your Eclipse

Comment: You must import your project as a maven project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot obviously shows that your `.project` and `.classpath`, which determine what your project should be in Eclipse, is wrong and since its lack a "Maven Dependencies" library node, that it was not imported correctly.

As you are using Maven, you should:

1. Remove the project from your workspace
2. Remove the `.project` and `.classpath` from your filesystem
3. Let m2e do that work for you: go to *File* > *Import* > **Existing Maven Project** (see [part 3 of this site](https://qaautomation.expert/2019/10/07/maven-how-to-import-maven-project-into-eclipse/) for [this particular screenshot](https://qaautomationexpert.files.wordpress.com/2021/02/image-271.png)).
4. Wait a little bit for the project to refresh
5. You should then have the proper `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources` (etc) configured in Eclipse.

Once that's done, you may

1. Either stick to Maven import for your project and remove `.project/.classpath`: in this mode, be sure to tell your friend to remove the project and reimport them properly. Usually, m2e does a good job even if a `.project/.classpath` was there.
2. Commit the updated .project/.classpath and ask your friend to update/refresh the project (I tend to use right click on the project, then Refresh than pressing F5).

This will have to be done each time you update the pom.xml or the project settings.

Do note that m2e will only synchronize:

1. The project layout (main source and resources, test source and resource )
2. The Java configuration (Java 8, Java 11, ...) based on maven-compiler-plugin
3. The encoding, based on `project.build.sourceEncoding` and the like.
4. The dependencies based on dependencies and dependencyManagement, as well as profile

The `.settings` in Eclipse will contains stuff like Coding Styles, Clean up and so on.

You may want to keep them under scm or use [Oomph](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Oomph) to share the preferences as well as other Eclipse plugins.

An alternative would be to use a maven project configurer such as:

- [m2e-code-quality](https://github.com/m2e-code-quality/m2e-code-quality) to bind Maven and Eclipse settings for checkstyle, findbugs/spotbugs, pmd.
- [eclipse-settings-maven-plugin](https://github.com/bsi-software/eclipse-settings-maven-plugin) to configure your project using maven.

Answer (score 0):

Well maybe the resources are not downloaded automatically and your friend has to update the project with maven.

1. Right click on project
2. Choose maven and update
3. update project and if it does not change anything try force snapshot

Can your friend open Eclipse market place? Could you please in future include the classes and pom.xml, share github link so that everybody can lookup maybe their is something wrong....